# Going on last rline in textbox

Tags: c#

How can i get the last line in a textbox by clicking a button. With that code i get the first line ...

```
 private void btnProbe_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

       string[] first = txtRec.Text.Split(new char[] { '\n' }[0]);
       probe.Text = txtRec.Lines[0];
    }
```

Comment: Why are you calculating `first` but not doing anything with it? Why are you creating a `char` array just to get the single element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to split the string, just use:

```
private void btnProbe_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if(txtRec.Lines.Length>1)        
        probe.Text = txtRec.Lines[txtRec.Lines.Length - 1];
}
```

Comment: @NikolaObretenov is your last line blank?

Comment: if you mean last line like a view in a textbox... yes Ill try now to fill the whole textbox (i have a scroll anyway ...) it must count the last line ...

Comment: Ok i done it with Length - 2, i don't know why it is going to count the lines when i type -2... now it works even i have blank in my textbox

Comment: @NikolaObretenov It should work, just tested. How do you fill your txtRec textBox, maybe you have some newline strings that you can't see.

Comment: @NikolaObretenov Check the edited answer, you must be sure not to make IndexOutOfBoundsException

Answer (score 2):

Using LINQ, the code becomes much more elegant:

```
var lastLineString = txtRec.Lines.Last();
```

** Remember to add System.Linq to your usages.

Answer (score 1):

You're fine with just taking the count of the lines:

```
txtRec.Lines[txtRec.Lines.Length - 1];
```

txtRec.Lines.Length gives you the count of lines; because array-counting starts with 0, you need to substract 1

Plus, you don't need your line starting with "first".

Answer (score 0):

Your first line is useless and creepy.

```
 private void btnProbe_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   probe.Text = txtRec.Lines[txtRec.Lines.Length - 1];
 }
```